# List of strings won't update on setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn Flutter and can't understand what's going wrong here.
I have the main widget (The one that comes with the Flutter starter app), I removed the body, and added a `SearchBar` widget and a `PhotoList` widget, I'm trying to fetch data from an API, and update the PhotoList widget to show the images I fetched.

This is what I have:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedSegment = 0;
  Networking _service = Networking();
  List<String> urls;

  @override
  void initState() {
    urls = [];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SearchBar(
                  onSearchTap: (String value) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> map;
                    List<dynamic> results;
                    dynamic urls;
                    dynamic thumbs;
                    List<String> image_urls = new List<String>();

                    _service.fetchPhotos(value).then((value) => {
                          map = jsonDecode(value.body),
                          results = map["results"],
                          thumbs = results.map((e) => e["urls"]),
                          for (dynamic thumb in thumbs)
                            {image_urls.add(thumb["thumb"].toString())},
                          this.setState(() {
                            urls = image_urls;
                          })
                        });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ButtonGroup(
                    titles: ["Photos", "Collections", "User"],
                    current: _selectedSegment,
                    onTab: (selected) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedSegment = selected;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            PhotosGrid(urls: urls),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I printed the urls after the setState, and it does have values that prints to the console.
But it won't update in the PhotosGrid, to my understanding, the setState should refresh the `build` function, so the PhotosGrid should refresh too, but nothing happens.
This is my PhotosGrid widget:

```
class PhotosGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> urls;

  PhotosGrid({Key key, this.urls}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PhotosGridState createState() => _PhotosGridState();
}

class _PhotosGridState extends State<PhotosGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (var url in widget.urls) PhotoCard(url)
            //for (var url in widget.urls) PhotoCard(url),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my PhotoCard:

```
class PhotoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  String imageUrl;

  PhotoCard({Key key, this.imageUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhotoCardState createState() => _PhotoCardState();
}

class _PhotoCardState extends State<PhotoCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 32),
        child: Container(
          height: 220,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(widget.imageUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can't understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Inside the onSearchTap you declare a dynamic url, then in setState you're using urls = image_urls; instead of this.urls = image_urls;

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing it, but still nothing. image_urls has values but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I find weird this doens't work in the first place

```
onSearchTap: (String value) {
  Map<String, dynamic> map;
  List<dynamic> results;
  // dynamic urls; delete this line
  List<String> image_urls = <String>[];

  // does this future completes without error?
  _service.fetchPhotos(value).then((value) => {
        map = jsonDecode(value.body),
        results = map["results"],
        thumbs = results.map((e) => e["urls"]),
        for (dynamic thumb in thumbs)
          image_urls.add(thumb["thumb"].toString()),
        setState(() => urls = image_urls)
  });
},
```

UPDATE

I just made a minimal reproducible project and run it without problem

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

Future<List<String>> thumbnails(int value) {
  String url = 'https://picsum.photos/id/x/200/300'; //dummy api to retrieve pics
  List<String> myThumbs = [];
  int n = value ?? 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) myThumbs.add(
    url.replaceFirst('x', i.toString()) //just change x for any number to retrieve a real url from the api
  );

  myThumbs.shuffle();

  return Future<List<String>>.value(myThumbs);
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> urls;

  @override
  void initState() {
    urls = <String>[];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
             child: TextField(
              key: Key('MyTextField'),
              onSubmitted: (String value) {
                thumbnails(int.tryParse(value)).then((list) {
                  setState(() => urls = list);
                });
              },
             ),
            ),
            PhotosGrid(urls: urls),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> urls;

  PhotosGrid({Key key, this.urls}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PhotosGridState createState() => _PhotosGridState();
}

class _PhotosGridState extends State<PhotosGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (var url in widget.urls) PhotoCard(imageUrl: url)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;

  PhotoCard({Key key, this.imageUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhotoCardState createState() => _PhotoCardState();
}

class _PhotoCardState extends State<PhotoCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 32),
        child: Container(
          height: 220,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(widget.imageUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of your SearchBar I just put a TextField (because I don't have the SearchBar class, but it should work the same). When submitted i try to parse it to a number (please insert numbers) and then create a list from a dummy api of pics (I dont have the service you're using). The idea it's the same, I still use all your classes and run it without problem

[image: Example]

My only advice would be try to minimize the number of variables (or creating them only where you need them) and avoid using dynamic if you already know the kind of value you're expecting

```
onSearchTap: (String value) {

   _service.fetchPhotos(value).then((value) => {
    //declare them here if you only will use them inside the then future
     Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(value.body),
     List<dynamic> results = map["results"],
     var thumbs = results.map((e) => e["urls"]),
     List<String> image_urls = <String>[];
     for (var thumb in thumbs) image_urls.add(thumb["thumb"].toString()),
     setState(() => urls = image_urls);
  });
 },
```

Comment: Yes, it does complete without an error, I also print image_urls and it has values.

Comment: And you print urls too? At the beginning of the build method to see if the setState is changing

Comment: Yes, I did and it seems like urls does get the values. Maybe the problem is with PhotoCard, I will upload the PhotoCard as soon as possible.

Comment: I added the PhotoCard, could you please take a look?